# In node.js, Buffer.from() method is throwing "ascii is not a function" error

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

In Node.js, Buffer class is global. When I am trying to execute below line of code in Visual Studio code, node.js is throwing exception.

My Code

```
var buffer = Buffer.from('Hello','ascii');
```

Exception

```
TypeError: ascii is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
```

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Buffer.from()` you're seeing is actually `ArrayBuffer.from()` which has different behavior. Fortunately for LTS users, [node v4.5.0](https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.5.0/api/buffer.html) was recently released which *does* include the new node `Buffer` APIs (including the custom `Buffer.from()`). Also, node v6.x (which will become the next LTS branch in October) has had these APIs for awhile now.